# Difference between ‘strategy’ and ‘plan’

Tags: difference

What is difference between **strategy** and **plan**?

> The coming year may herald a change in **strategy/plan** for major publishers

Answer (score 0):

Whether it be business management, military operations, or whatever, these involve two different levels of process, organization, and time.

The word "[**strategy**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/strategy)" shares the same root as "[stratosphere](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stratosphere)," which is very high up in the sky, the highest you can get in the sky before the sky turns into outer space. Strategy is nebulous and big-picture, not at all detailed but just very broad strokes that rough out a series of ways and a long-run timeline to accomplish a larger mission in order to realize a vision while being vague on the particulars.

A "[**plan**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/plan)" is "[tactical](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tactical)," which shares a root with "[tactile](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tactile)," meaning it's hands-on, boots-on-the-ground, so close you can touch it. A plan isn't nebulous, big-picture, or broad strokes, but is clearly outlined and defined on the particulars and details, or it should be if it's a good plan. A plan, too, will have a timeline, but its timeline is short-run, so if a plan is a tactic towards achieving a strategy, then its short-run timeline is but one component timeline within the strategy's long-run timeline.

Strategy flows from a mission that flows from a vision. Strategy is comprised of sweeping objectives and a timeline for completing them. How a strategy is carried out is with tactics. Tactics involve plans, detailed and ways and means on a schedule to achieving strategic objectives that are part of a greater mission and an even greater vision. Implementing a strategy involves organizing and carrying out multiple plans and often a series of plans that will come together to carry out a strategy over a longer timeline.

Not all plans are part of strategies, but hopefully, by my explaining plans in reference to strategies when they are part of strategies may help you understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary will likely tell you that a 'plan' is a series of pre-made decisions to achieve a purpose or goal, and that a 'strategy' is just a highly-detailed plan. However, native English speakers perceive a bigger difference between the two. While a strategy may be more *complex*, it is less specific than a plan. A plan will detail very specifically what actions are to be taken, whereas a strategy is more about setting long-term goals and a broad methodology for *how* those goals will be achieved.

For example, your 'plan' for the weekend might be to go outside for a picnic. But if it rains then you can't carry out your plan. When people have an alternative for such a situation, that is often spoken of as a completely different plan - a 'backup' plan, or a 'contingency' plan.

By contrast, *strategies* have contingency built into them. For example, a strategy for a game of Chess is concerned with evaluation of chess positions and setting of goals and long-term plans for future play. A chess player cannot 'plan' all their moves precisely in sequence - they have to wait to see how they other player makes their moves. But the 'strategy' will guide their choices.

In an example closer to the one you state, different businesses may develop their own unique 'plans', yet they may still be said to follow similar *strategies*. A business strategy might be to 'improve customer service', but two businesses may achieve that by implementing very different plans.

If you mean to say that businesses are setting out lists of things they will do this year, then I'd say they were making new *plans*. However, if they are going in very bold, new directions, or adopting new business models, I'd say they were changing *strategies*.